# regex - get specific part of title

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a title structured this way:

```
<title>WebsiteName | Page title | Slogan</title>
```

Currently, in C# I use this, to get the title out:

```
Regex.Match(pageSource,
                @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;
```

But, what I want to get out is only the page title.

Comment: is that html you are parsing?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match in the title you have provided?  Just `Page Title`?

Comment: Split your problem up. Use som form of DOM parsing tool for parsing the html. See the answers below. Then use regex or a simple string.Split on the title content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@"\<title[^>]*\>[^|]*\|\s*(?<Title>[^|]*?)\|[^<]*\</title\>"

"\<title[^>]*\>"   //Title tag
"[^|]*"            //Everything up to the first pipe
"\|\s*"            //First pipe and any leading white space
"(?<Title>[^|]*?)" //The page title section between the pipes
"\|"               //Second pipe
"[^<]*\"           //Everything after the first pipe up to closing title tag
"</title\>"        //closing title tag
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid parsing html with `regex`.

You can do it using [htmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

---

This would get the title of html!

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);    
string title=doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText;
```

Now after getting the page title you can get the required data with this regex

Considering your title would always be in the same form as given in the example of yours you can use

```
(?<=\|).+?(?=\|)
```

Comment: I think he wants `Page Title` from within the title tag?  It's not entirely clear...

Comment: My first thought was using HAP but decided not to cause I thought it would be slower..

Comment: @GregaMenih there wouldn't be any **major** performance difference but using `htmlagilitypack` you would be more sure with parsing..

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to get `Page Title` then try this:

```
\|(.*)\|
```

Your second match will contain the title if you pass the string you provided.  If you find yourself doing anything more complex than this, then regex probably isn't your tool.  There are better ways to parse HTML.